# iisreset error on windows 10

Tags: iis, windows-10, iisreset

I have recently upgraded my desktop from Windows 7 to Windows 10

However when I run iisrest from an administrator console, I am getting the following error:

> Restart attempt failed.
>   The IIS Admin Service or the World Wide Web Publishing Service, or a service dependent on them failed to start.  The service, or dependent services, may had an error during its startup or may be disabled.

I initially checked my services, and there is no longer the IIS Admin service. I then checked the windows features, and as per nearly every article on the web that discusses installing IIS, I have selected Internet Information Services.

I have checked and the web service has restarted, Is this a new feature of Windows10 that the IIS Admin service is no longer required.
Is there an additional step that I need to do that will install the service

Or is this now an issue with IISReset and I can ignore the error.

I have also tested this on a freshly installed Windows 10 box, and running IISReset gives the same error, and once again have verified via Windows features that IIS is installed

I can access website locally with no problems either

Comment: can you check Windows Event log and find error?

Comment: No error in the Application event log that I would attribute to the iisreset.   Did see this in the system event log but no idea if its related.The Net.Tcp Listener Adapter service depends on the Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service service which failed to start because of the following error: 
The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

Answer (score 25):

After @Zam recommended looking in the event log, and poking around a lot, the issue was that services "Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service", "Net.Tcp Listener Adapter" on my machine are disabled by default.

After starting these services, and changing the Startup Type to "Automatic (Delayed Start)", iisreset no longer gives me error

Comment: Same here, annoying issue, 5 minutes before all worked fantastic :S
When I start the Net.Tcp Service works fine.

Answer (score 5):

After executing `iisreset /start` and facing the described failure, just execute `iisreset /status` to see the list of services to which IIS is dependent and which ones are stile stopped. In Windows 10 this stopped service is usually "**Net.Msmq Listener Adapter (NetMsmqActivator)**" and if you try to start it, you will encounter the following error:

[image]

Because it is dependent on a service called "**Microsoft Messaging Queue (MSMQ)**" which is not installed by default in Windows 10.
Just follow these steps to install it:

1. in the Run command window type `appwiz.cpl` to open "**Programs and Features**" item from the Control Panel
2. in the "Programs and Features" select "**Turn Windows features on or off**" in the top left corner
3. in the "**Windows Features**" scroll down to see "**Microsoft Messaging Queue (MSMQ) Server**" and select it (it doesn't need to be selected completely)
4. restart the computer

Now, if you execute `iisreset /start` it will be executed with no problem.

Answer (score 3):

For this problem, start the following services in windows:

1. Net.Tcp Listener Adapter
2. Net.Pipe Listener Adapter
3. Net.Msmq Listener Adapter
4. Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service
5. Messaging Queuing
6. W3SVC Service

Answer (score 1):

It should be IIS Admin Service. I had the same problem and was able to resolve once IIS Admin Service is started and set to Automatic

Comment: By "set to Automatic", are you referring to the Startup Type? If so, can you provide information on how to set that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Netskope Client running, it might be closing the connection and causing the error. If possible, disable Netskope Client and the error should be resolved.